# System.ObjectDisposedException при ajax post запросе

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core

отправляю из представления такой запрос

```
$.post('/Hero/UseItem', itemID);
```

метод контроллера Hero

```
public async void UseItem(int itemID)
    {
        var hero = await _context.Hero.Include(x => x.Inventory).ThenInclude(x => x.HeroItem).ThenInclude(x => x.Item)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserID == User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));           
    }
```

выдает такое

> System.ObjectDisposedException: "Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task вместо void

```
public async Task UseItem([FromForm] int itemID)
```

view

```
    function useItem(itemID) {
        $.post('/Hero/UseItem', { 'itemID':itemID }, function () {
            loadInventory();
            loadEquipment();
        });
    }
```